# Determining origin of norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Reading a script i've found task in which i had to determine whether each norm $$\|x\|_{p}=\left(\sum |x_{i}|^{p}\right)^{1/p}$$ origins from scalar product. Assuming $$p=2$$ i got, it comes from standard scalar product. $$\|x\|_{2}=\langle x,x\rangle^{1/2}$$ no luck for others.
Tip i got was to use Parallelogram law and describe it in norm language.
I get.
$$\|x+y\|^{2}+\|x-y\|^{2}=2\|x\|^2+2\|y\|^{2}$$
I just don't see how should i use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let:
$$
x=(1,1,0,0 \cdots) \qquad y=(1,-1,0,0 \cdots)
$$
we have:
$$
\|x\|_p=2^{1/p}=\|y\|_p
$$
and
$$
x+y=(2,0,0\cdots) \Rightarrow \|x+y\|_p=2
$$
$$
x-y=(0,2,0\cdots) \Rightarrow \|x-y\|_p=2
$$
so the parallelogram low becomes:
$$
\|x+y\|_p^2+\|x-y\|_p^2=2\left(\|x\|_p^2+\|y\|_p^2 \right)
$$
i.e:
$$
8=2\left(2^{2/p}+2^{2/p} \right) \iff 2=2^{2/p}
$$
that gives $p=2$.

This means that the parallelogram low is verified only if $p=2$ and only in this case the norm can be derived from an inner product.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that

$$x = (1, 0, 0, \cdots), \ \ \ y = (0,1,0, 0, \cdots)$$

in $\ell _p$ satisfies the parallelogram law only when $p = 2$. Indeed, the right hand side is $2\cdot 2^{\frac 2p}$ and the left hand side is $4$. Thus $\ell_p$-norm does not come from an inner product.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but the example seems to satisfy the parallelogram law for $p=1$ as well. But then I think that $p$ must be even to ensure the norm is positive definite ?

Comment: I get $2 \cdot 2^{\frac 2p}$ on one side and $4$ the other side..@TomCollinge (Indeed now my answer is almost the same as that of Emilio)

Comment: With $p=1$ I get $(1+1)^2 +(1-1)^2 =4 = 2.1 + 2.1$

Comment: See my extended comment posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this an extended comment......

Are you sure that your norm is $\|x\|_p=\left(\sum x_i^{p}\right)^{1/p}$  and not in fact $\|x\|_p=\left(\sum |x_i|^{p}\right)^{1/p}$

See for example the wiki entry on p-norm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm.

If the two answers given assume the p-norm then they are correct.

If your original statement is correct, then it cannot be a norm for any odd value of $p$ since $\|(-1, 0, 0, ...)\|$ is not positive for $p=1$ and is not real for any odd $p > 1$.

Comment: It's as you say, i've accidentally wrote it without absolute value. Now correct.